# jQuery looping slider troubles

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I'm trying to get the following slider to loop by setting `.css({"left" : "0px"})` on the `ul.slider-ul`. I've got  a `console.log("Loop")` going to check that the `if` statement is working, which it is.

HTML

```
<div class="slider-small-box sone slider-box">
    <ul class="slider-ul">
        <li>
            <img src="spacer.gif" class="slider-img">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="spacer2.gif" class="slider-img">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="spacer2.gif" class="slider-img">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="spacer2.gif" class="slider-img">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slider-box {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.slider-box ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: auto;
}
.slider-box > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.slider-small-box > ul > li > img {
    width: 270px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #333333;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.slider-large-box > ul > li > img {
    width: 550px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #333333;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

jQuery

```
function slider(x) {

    function loop() { //Sets repeating random value
        var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (5000 - 1000)) + 1000;
        slider(x)
    }

    var size = $(x).parent().width() //Getting the size of the viewport div

    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (5000 - 1000)) + 1000; //Sets initial random value

    setTimeout( function() { //Animating the slider to the left with a random time
        $(x).animate({"left" : "-=" + size + "px"}, 2000)
        loop();
    }, rand);

    var width = 0;
    $(x).find('li').each(function() { //Finding the total width of the images
        width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
        return(width)
    });

    var offset = size - width + "px"; //The point at which to reset the slider

    var pos = $(x).position().left + "px"; //The current left position of the slider

    var $this = $(this)
    if(pos == offset) {
        console.log("Loop"); //This gets called out
        $this.animate({"left" : "0px"}); //This doesn't set the css value
    };
}


$(function() {
    $("ul.slider-ul").each(function() {
        $this = $(this)
        slider($this)
    });
 });
```

See the fiddle here: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/et9xX/)

EDIT:

For clarification the issue is the if statement at the bottom of the jQuery. For some reason it is not resetting the `left` value of the element's css to create the looping action.

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: @Apolo My problem is that the loop `if` statement isn't working(`if(pos == offset){}`). The slider just continues to move to the left.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your are missing a lot of ';' in your javascript code :

---

### EDIT

here is a working code : (DEMO [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/et9xX/14/))

```
function slider(x) {    

    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (5000 - 1000)) + 1000;
    
    // go to left
    setTimeout(function () {
        var size = x.parent().width();
        var futureLoc = x.offset().left + x.outerWidth(true) - size;
        var parentLoc = x.parent().offset().left;
        if (futureLoc <= parentLoc) {
            console.log("Loop");
            x.animate({
                "left": "0px"
            },function(){slider(x);});
        } else {
            x.animate({
                "left": "-=" + size + "px"
            }, 2000,function(){slider(x);});
        }
    }, rand);
}


$("ul.slider-ul").each(function () {
    slider($(this));
});
```

I had to change a lot of things and the animation is empty before it reset so you will have to play with it do have a perfect animation.

#### edit2 : I changed the code to make it reset properly

Comment: `;` is not really required if using the Enter key to terminate the line code. BTW you should try the code first to be sure it works before posting an answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Seems i've been in too much of a flurry trying to get it to work and I've missed a few. However, that does not resolve the issue at hand.

Comment: Well, i don't delete but I will edit once I get what's going on

Comment: @Mallander, can you explain what you are trying to check with `if(pos==offset)` ?

Comment: @Apolo `offset` is the `left` value at which the slider should be reset. `pos` is the current `left` position of the slider. So I am checking to see whether the **current** position of the slider is **equal** to the point at which it should **reset**.

Comment: Thanks for that @Apolo it led me in the right direction! Got it working now with a bit more optimisation thanks to you!